# ¿Cómo detengo una canción?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de música en Java, para reproducir la música uso el siguiente código, que esta en un botón:

```
AudioClip sound;
 sound = java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("/sound1.wav"));
 sound.play();
```

Cuando quiero detener la canción uso el siguiente código, que se encuentra en otro botón:

```
AudioClip sound;
sound = java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("/sound1.wav"));
sound.stop();
```

Sin embargo al darle click al botón, la música no se detiene. Saben por que sucede esto y como podría solucionarlo?, cualquier recomendación o sugerencia la apreciaría mucho.